# Manually creating interactive PDFs

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

For reasons tedious to explain, I need to create simple PDFs from a C# application without using any third-party libraries. The PDFs in question need to include text and line drawings, and if possible should include images, radio buttons, and text fields. I've been reading Adobe's [documentation](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf), which is for the most part straightforward, but so far have been unable to figure out how to make interactive fields actually appear on the document.

For example, consider the partial test PDF document described below:

```
1 0 obj
  << /Type /Catalog
     /Pages 2 0 R
     /AcroForm 6 0 R
  >>
endobj

...

6 0 obj
  << /Fields [ 7 0 R ]
     /DR 5 0 R
  >>
endobj

7 0 obj
  << /FT /Btn
     /Ff 65536
     /Kids [ 8 0 R 9 0 R ]
  >>
endobj

8 0 obj
  << /Parent 7 0 R
     /AS /FieldA
     /AP 10 0 R
  >>
endobj

9 0 obj
  << /Parent 8 0 R
     /AS /FieldB
     /AP 10 0 R
  >>
endobj

10 0 obj
  << /N
    << /FieldA 11 0 R
       /FieldB 12 0 R
       /Off 13 0 R
    >>
  >>
endobj

11 0 obj
  << /Length  59 >>
stream
  BT
    /F1 12 Tf
    0 0 Td
    (Field A) Tj
  ET
endstream
endobj

...
```

Where `5 0 R` references a resource dictionary containing the font `/F1` and `12 0 R` and `13 0 R` reference streams similar to `11 0 R` with the string replaced by `Field B` and `Off` respectively.

What changes do I need to make to the document to cause the fields thus defined to actually appear on a page?

Edit: Since mkl asked, here's the whole pdf (extra line breaks removed to save space)

```
%PDF-1.7
%¥±ë

1 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Pages 2 0 R >> endobj
2 0 obj << /Type /Pages /Kids [3 0 R] /Count 1 /MediaBox [0 0 200 200] >> endobj
3 0 obj << /Type /Page /Parent 2 0 R /Resources 5 0 R /Contents 4 0 R >> endobj

4 0 obj << /Length 39 >>
stream
BT /F1 12 Tf 0 0 Td (Hello World) Tj ET
endstream
endobj

5 0 obj << /Font << /F1 << /Type /Font /Subtype /Type1 /BaseFont /Helvetica >> >> >> endobj
6 0 obj << /Fields [ 7 0 R ] /DR 5 0 R >> endobj
7 0 obj << /FT /Btn /Ff 65536 /Kids [ 8 0 R 9 0 R ] >> endobj
8 0 obj << /Parent 7 0 R /AS /FieldA /AP 10 0 R >> endobj
9 0 obj << /Parent 7 0 R /AS /FieldB /AP 10 0 R >> endobj
10 0 obj << /N << /FieldA 11 0 R /FieldB 12 0 R /Off 13 0 R >> >> endobj

11 0 obj << /Length 59 >>
stream
BT /F1 12 Tf 0 0 Td (Field A) Tj ET
endstream
endobj

12 0 obj << /Length 39 >>
stream
BT /F1 12 Tf 0 0 Td (Field B) Tj ET
endstream
endobj

13 0 obj << /Length 39 >>
stream
BT /F1 12 Tf 0 0 Td (Off... ) Tj ET 94
endstream
endobj

xref
0 14
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000018 00000 n 
0000000068 00000 n 
0000000150 00000 n 
0000000233 00000 n 
0000000327 00000 n
0000000420 00000 n
0000000470 00000 n
0000000533 00000 n
0000000592 00000 n
0000000651 00000 n
0000000727 00000 n
0000000821 00000 n
0000000917 00000 n
trailer << /Root 1 0 R /Size 5 >>
startxref
1013
%%EOF
```

Comment: Please share the whole PDF for analysis.

Comment: your content isn't hiding down the bottom of the page is it? (0, 0 is bottom left)

Comment: @lecstor Shouldn't be, since text is written up and to the right from the cursor position. Either way, at no point in what I've written are the buttons placed on a page.

Comment: cool, yeh, just thought I'd check. Some would definitely be on the page, just not at the top 8)

Comment: @mkl Added it at the end. Unreasonably long, so removed extra line breaks. Recounted byte counts to make sure they were still accurate for xref table.

Comment: @P... Ok, looking at your PDF there are multiple shortcomings, but Mihai Iancu was faster naming many of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the full file you posted I see several issues (there might be more):

- The document catalog does not include an /AcroForm entry
- The page does not include an /Annots entry with links to field widgets
- Field definitions 8 and 9 are incomplete, they do not include the widget annotation entries. These entries specify the field location on the page
- Your field is a pushbutton, it does not have different appearance states, the /N appearance should be a reference to an appearance stream (11, 12 or 13)
- Field appearances 11, 12, 13 are invalid, entries such as /Type, /Subtype, /BBox, /Resources are missing

Update: below you can find a minimum file structure for a radio button.

```
1 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog /Version /1.4 /Pages 8 0 R /AcroForm <</Fields [2 0 R ]>> >>
endobj
2 0 obj
<< /FT /Btn /T (Radio) /V /Off /Kids [5 0 R 3 0 R ] /Ff 32768 >>
endobj
3 0 obj
<< /Type /Annot /F 4 /Rect [250  667  270  687  ] /Subtype /Widget /AS /Off /AP << /N << /Two 7 0 R /Off 6 0 R >> >> /Parent 2 0 R /P 4 0 R >>
endobj
4 0 obj
<< /Type /Page /Contents null /MediaBox [0  0  612  792  ] /Parent 8 0 R /Annots [5 0 R 3 0 R ] >>
endobj
5 0 obj
<< /Type /Annot /F 4 /Rect [150  667  170  687  ] /Subtype /Widget /AS /Off /AP << /N << /One 7 0 R /Off 6 0 R >> >> /Parent 2 0 R /P 4 0 R >>
endobj
6 0 obj
<< /Type /XObject /Subtype /Form /BBox [0  0  20  20  ] /Length 74 >>
stream
/DeviceRGB CS 0 0 0 SC 1 w 0.5 0.5 m 19.5 0.5 l 19.5 19.5 l 0.5 19.5 l h S
endstream
endobj
7 0 obj
<< /Type /XObject /Subtype /Form /BBox [0  0  20  20  ] /Length 55 >>
stream
/DeviceRGB cs 0 0 0 sc 0 0 m 20 0 l 20 20 l 0 20 l h f
endstream
endobj
8 0 obj
<< /Type /Pages /Count 1 /Kids [4 0 R ] >>
endobj
```

You can download [minimum radio button sample](http://xfiniumpdf.com/download/customersamples/radiobutton.minimum.pdf) and a [more detailed radio button sample](http://xfiniumpdf.com/download/customersamples/radiobutton.full.pdf).

Using our [XFINIUM.PDF Inspector](http://xfiniumpdf.com/xfinium-pdf-inspector/xfinium-pdf-inspector-overview.html) you can visualize the PDF file structure.

Comment: *"Your field is a pushbutton, it does not have different appearance states, the /N appearance should be a reference to an appearance stream"* - or... the **Ff** value should be corrected to make the field a CheckBox or RadioButton. But even then three states is a bit too much.

Comment: Alright, I based my file off of the example on page 441 of the PDF. While I made some mistakes myself (misread the bit numbers on Ff as 0-indexed rather than 1-indexed), it's obvious that that example is ludicrously incomplete, and simply adopting the changes you suggest does not fix it. Is there an example of an actual, working radio button anywhere at all that you can suggest looking at?

Comment: @P... there are so many PDFs out there, many of them with forms and in particular radio buttons...

Comment: @mkl And good luck finding any unobfuscated, if you don't already know where to look. Adding 'by hand' to search terms just adds results about Acrobat's 'hand' tool.

Comment: Thank you so much for the example and resources! I can't imagine a more helpful answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Your fields will need to include what are known as "appearances" which are XObjects that contain the drawing instructions used to create the visual appearance of the field. See section 12.5.5 of the PDF Specification. Alternatively, you can set the NeedAppearances property of the AcroForm entry in the document catalog to true. See section 12.7.2 of the PDF specification. Setting this to true will cause a conforming viewer to create the appearances of the fields based on their properties. However, you can't count on most viewers to do this.

Comment: Is that not what my objects 9, 10, and 11 are in the example?

Comment: Sorry, objects 8, 9, and 10 are what I meant.

Comment: XObjects have a few required properties that I'm not seeing in your code. Subtype and BBox are two. Type is optional but in practice I find it to be required. See section 8.10.2 of the spec. If you're able to see this PDF in something like Adobe Reader or Acrobat, that's only because it's being repaired before you see it. My PDF parsing tool can't read it at all. You tight try opening your file in iText RUPS to see if it's actually valid.

Comment: I also don't see an AcroForm dictionary in the Catalog, your Fields are there, but not hanging off the right object.